# What is the difference between protein translated by a free ribosome and protien translated by a ribosome attached to endoplasmic reticulem?

Tags: cell-biology

There are protiens translated by free ribosomes and proteins translated by attached ribosomes.  But how do these two types of protein differ from each other? I am just talking about a eukaryotic cell. I know that proteins made by free ribosomes do not have a covering but proteins made by attached ribosome gradully have a vesicle around them but I am not able to understand what difference in use does the vesicle make? (I am new here so pls forgive if there are mistakes in my question)

Comment: As a newcomer to Stack Exchange Biology, you may not realize that your question has a couple of problems that may result in it being ruled off-topic. The first is that it looks rather like a homework question, for which there are specific rules you can find in the [Help](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). One of these — which also applies generally — is that you should show that you have made an attempt to answer this question yourself. This means doing some [research](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Try Wikipedia on free and membrane-bound ribosomes.

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!